# Need help merging two LINQ statements

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am editing my code that used to be just

```
     return phases
            .OfType<ServicePhase>()
            .Where(p => p.Service.Code == par.Service.Code)
            .Cast<ParPhase>()
```

however now i want it to include both

```
 return phases
                .OfType<ServicePhase>()
                .Where(p => p.Service.Code == par.Service.Code)
                .Cast<ParPhase>()

             .OfType<ParTypePhase>()
            .Where(p => p.ParType.Code == par.Type.Code)
            .Cast<ParPhase>();
```

How can i merge both of these together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Concat` or `Union` method.

Sample:

```
var result = 
    phases
        .OfType<ServicePhase>()
        .Where(p => p.Service.Code == par.Service.Code)
        .Cast<ParPhase>()
        .Union(
            phases.OfType<ParTypePhase>()
            .Where(p => p.ParType.Code == par.Type.Code)
            .Cast<ParPhase>()
         );
```

Comment: i tryed putting the second query in .union<query 2> but it keeps getting errors

Comment: Edit your question and show us how you're trying to do the `Union` and what error message you get.

Answer (score 2):

```
return phases
            .Where(p => ((p is ServicePhase) && (p as ServicePhase).Service.Code == par.Service.Code) || 
                        ((p is ParTypePhase) && (p as ParTypePhase).ParType.Code == par.Type.Code))
            .Cast<ParPhase>()
```

This works because if `p` is not a `ServicePhase`, this line `(p as ServicePhase).Service.Code` which would be `object reference not set to an instance of an object` is never evaluated.

```
false && NeverGoingToGetCalled()
```

because false AND anything is always false. It's called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) if you care to read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which of these you mean. The first is if you want to further restrict the list, the second if you want to expand it.

```
from p in phrases
where p.Service.Code == par.Service.Code && p.ParType.Code == par.Type.Code
select new ParPhase(p)
```

or

```
from p in phrases
where p.Service.Code == par.Service.Code || p.ParType.Code == par.Type.Code
select new ParPhase(p)
```

Comment: I would suspect that if the `ParPhase` is of type `ParTypePhase` that trying to call `par.Service.Code` would cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easier if think about Specification Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Here is the combined query:

```
return phases.OfType<ServicePhase>()
.Where(p => 
{
  bool tmpResult = p.Service.Code == par.Service.Code;
  if(tmpResult && p is ParTypePhase)
  {
      tmpResult = (p as ParTypePhase).ParType.Code == par.Type.Code;
  }
  return tmpResult;
}).Cast<ParPhase>()
```